# Watching external local library while serving app

Tags: angular

I have a main app, and some libraries which are independant (not part of the main app).
For now when I work on a library I include the .tgz in main app's package.json.
Problem is I have to build/pack the library first and then serve the main app to see changes.

Is there a way to serve main app while watching changes in library ? I know that I can build --watch the library, but I still need to pack to get the .tgz

Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm provides a `link` command that can be used to link your local library app to the main app.

Just follow these steps below to link your local library.

1. Open your library application and navigate to the `dist/<your_lib>` folder. Make sure you have your build running in watch mode so that your main app can pickup the changes on the fly.
2. Run the command `npm link`.
3. Open you main application and run the following command on the root directory `npm link <lib_app_name>`.
4. Open angular.json of your main app. Under `architect -> build -> options`, add this property `"preserveSymlinks": true`.
5. Now add the lib app module in the **app.module.ts** of your main app and start using the lib app components/services.
6. Build and serve your application as usual using `ng serve`. You app should now with the lib app components/services without any errors.

If you are wondering how this works, `npm link` creates a symlink to your lib app, making your main app think that npm has installed your lib app in node_modules. For more information on this, refer [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html)

Comment: Thx a lot, I've tried and I guess this is the good way, but unfortunately my lib is in a scope and i'm not able to make it work. when I do "npm link" in the lib, I see that it creates a link in AppData/roaming/npm/node_modules named "mylib", and then I go in main app, I do "npm link @scope/mylib" and I can see that in AppData/roaming/npm/node_modules it creates a folder @scope and inside the folder another folder "mylib" is created.

Comment: Actually, when I navigate in the symlink which is in my mainApp/node_modules/@scope/myLib I see content of the MyLib dist/ folder. Is it supposed to be okay? When I try to serve the main app then I have errors like "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in "..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@scope\myLib\fesm5

Comment: @Lempkin This seems like a compilation error from the lib app, particularly with Peer dependencies specified in ng-package.json. Can you share your a minimal version of your lib app in Stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a path that points to the main export file in your library, in your `tsconfig.json`;

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "my-library": ["path/to/the/librarys/index.ts"]
    }
}
```